# async keyword Future<dynamic> problem in flutter/dart . I just want to know how the code is generating an error here below

Tags: android, flutter, dart, asynchronous, future

I dont know what is happening in this portion of code:

```
Future fnct()  {
   print("inside fnct()");
return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:4),()=>"hello");
 }


Future fnct2() async {
fnct().then((x){
print("inside then()");
  
});
```

here, this code works perfectly fine even without use of `await`  keyword . but as soon as I remove the `async` keyword, there is an error :

```
The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Future<dynamic>', is a potentially non-nullable type.
```

I have even heard you must nott have any Future<dynamic> type . Is it because of such error shown here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

> ```dart
> Future fnct2() async {
>   fnct().then((x) {
>     print("inside then()");
>   });
> }
> ```

You are declaring that `fnct2` returns a `Future` (which is shorthand for `Future<dynamic>`).  In `fnct2`'s body, the `Future` returned from the call to `Future.then(...)` is ignored and `fnct2` does not wait for it, and `fnct2` *immediately* returns.  Since there is no explicit return statement, it implicitly returns `null`.  That is, your code is the equivalent to:

```dart
Future<dynamic> fnct2() async {
  fnct().then((x) {
    print("inside then()");
  });
  return null;
}
```

Since the return type of `fnct2` is a `Future<dynamic>` and is marked `async`, any `return` statements in its body will be inferred to be `dynamic`. `dynamic` disables static type-checking, so returning anything (including nothing or `null`) is allowed, whether implicitly or explicitly.

The `async` keyword applies syntactic sugar that makes that equivalent to:

```dart
Future<dynamic> fnct2() {
  fnct().then((x) {
    print("inside then()");
  });
  return Future<dynamic>.value(null);
}
```

Now, if `fnct2` did not have the `async` keyword, omitting the explicit `return` statement would be equivalent to:

```dart
Future<dynamic> fnct2() {
  fnct().then((x) {
    print("inside then()");
  });
  return null; // ERROR
}
```

where it now implicitly returns `null` instead of `Future<dynamic>.value(null)`.  `fnct2` is declared to return a non-`null` `Future`, so implicitly returning `null` is not allowed.

Comment: is it also true that the async keyword also wraps the return type with Future ?

Comment: @WeirdoMemes Yes, that's part of the syntactic sugar I described in my answer that transforms the implicit `return null` into `return Future<dynamic>.value(null)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Future fnct2() async {
fnct().then((x){
print("inside then()");
});
```

The function `fnct2` is returning Future and it marked as async so the default return type is `Future<dynamic>`.

But as soon as you remove the async, the default return type changes to only `null` and function is expecting a Future to be returned.

So in this case you can use any of this,

```
Future fnct2()   {
fnct().then((x){
print("inside then()");
});
  return Future.value(0); // return some value
}
```

Mark Future to be nullable,

```
Future? fnct2()  {
fnct().then((x){
print("inside then()");
});
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Since you are using then on the `fnct ` there is no need to use Future as a return type and mark the function as async in `fnct2`.

Comment: I think the return type is rather Future<dynamic> rather than Future<void> as default.

Comment: Yes correct, Edited!